# How to split a large file into smaller files using VB.NET 2003?

Tags: .net, vb.net, file-io

I have a large file (2.7GB). I need to `split it` into smaller files. How to split a large file into smaller files using VB.NET 2003? Cannot use LINQ and the resources (cpu and memory) on operating environment are very limited (it is a shared hosting environment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read from the file with a stream, and write to the partial file - start a new file whenever you have reached the size you want your smaller files to be.