# Splitting Large Files With VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Does anyone know what the best way to split up large files in VB.NET? These files can be in excess of 10GB. I have found ways of doing it by googling all day! most of the solutions I have found almost work. But what I really want to know is what is the most efficient way to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: What type of data, binary or text? What methods have you tried? What problems are you having?

Comment: hi, @aphoria its binary data. I have tried loads of different examples. Some ran into memory problems, some split the file correctly but failed to do the last file and finish properly.  I have just found good reference here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955911/how-to-write-super-fast-file-streaming-code-in-c using the second chunk of code in the answer. This seems to work perfectly, only i don't know how to adapt this to do it in chunks... Perhaps you could advise?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you have stumbled on for example following topics. If so, didn't they fulfil your wishes or would you like other alternatives?

[How to split a large file into smaller files using VB.NET 2003?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696124/how-to-split-a-large-file-into-smaller-files-using-vb-net-2003)

[Split large file into smaller files by number of lines in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374040/split-large-file-into-smaller-files-by-number-of-lines-in-c)

Comment: I have seen plenty of examples thanks, What I'm looking for is some advice on the most efficient way to do this. As my application could be processing several of these very large files at any time. Thanks for the links though. I had seen the top one but not the bottom one.